# Adding JTextArea to JFrame not showing

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtextarea

I tried searching around and cant seem to find why my JTextArea isn't showing, I have a separate class to make a GUI but when I declare a new GUI in that class, the GUI pops up with the correct title and size but no TextArea.

```
    import java.awt.Container;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;     

    public class BaseballPlayerGUI extends JFrame {

        JTextArea arear = new JTextArea();

        public BaseballPlayerGUI() {
                this.setSize(500,500);
                this.setTitle("Baseball Players");
                this.setVisible(true);
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
                arear.setText("Why wont this show in TextArea!");
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I tried searching around and cant seem to find why my JTextArea isn't showing,

You didn't add the text area to the frame:

```
this.add(arear);
this.setSize(500,500);
```

Also, usually you add a text area to a scroll pane so you would probably use:

```
this.add(new JScrollPane(arear) );
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it had to use the .add method. I don't need to declare a JScrollPane? or its declared within that one line?

Comment: @Wilks: the place to search are the Swing tutorials. You can find links to them and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).

Comment: Yes in the second example the JScrollPane is created in that one line. You only need to define a variable for the scroll pane if you want to customize a property of the scroll pane.